# How can I handle forward slashes '/' in title when routing in Django templates?

Tags: python, django

My urls.py and template.html look as follows:

## urls.py

```
path('item/<str:title>/', views.ItemDetail.as_view(), name="item_detail'),
```

## template.html

```
<h3>Title: <a href="{% url 'item_detail' object.title %}">object.title</a></h3>
```

Right now, I do not prevent users from creating objects with a forward slash in them. That is probably a separate question

After a user creates an item with a forward slash, let's say `'Do 1/2 the work up front'`, how can I route to that item using that title? Right now I do not know how to handle the forward slash `/` and I'm getting the error:

> Reverse for 'item_detail' with arguments '('Do 1/2 the work up front',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
>   ['item\/(?P[^/]+)$']

I looked into [striptags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#striptags) but that was not what I needed.

Comment: Maybe you should use the id of the item instead of it's title.

Comment: That is really helpful, but that is not always practical. Django emphasizes beautiful URLs, so sometimes it is helpful to have text describing the URL, as opposed to numbers and random chars only. Does that make sense?

Comment: Although, your point here is very valid. I don't need this particular form to be "beautiful" or user friendly. That will work to solve this issue in the short term. Thanks.

Comment: I'm looking at the URL for this post `/questions/53419897/how-can-i-handle-forward-slashes-in-title-when-routing-in-django-templates`, it seems like they handle that character and probably any other character that will break the URL. I think you'll have to take care of anything that might break the URL. You might want to take a look at this [tutorial on slugs](https://keyerror.com/blog/slug-fields-an-alternative-approach). Django has their slugify package as well. It will remove invalid characters from user input - [it's called slugify](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/utils/)

Comment: Yes, you should link on slugs - store them in a separate field, which is automatically populated from the title field.

Answer (score 1):

In django str accepts everything except `/` symbol. So according to Django documentation,

`path - Matches any non-empty string, including the path separator, '/'. This allows you to match against a complete URL path rather than just a segment of a URL path as with str.`

However I recommend you to add a slug field which will convert your url into something like `this-is-your-url`